# Modify a node on the submit

Tags: nodes, forms

I would like to generate a forum for each article posted on the website. 
Actually what i'm able to do is create the forum before, write the article and match a field with the forum.

Now i would like to hide this field in the creation of the article (correct me if i'm wrong but i think it can be done with a $form['#access'] = false;) and create it on the submit of the article.

I would like to create the forum on the submit and match it with the field while it is invisible to the poster.

Do you know how i could do that ? Thanks by advance.

Comment: are you generating forum programmatically (in which case add your code), with rules other? and what field are you matching forum with?